# capture type of optional parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that will compute its return type from type of argument.

```
type Ret<A> = A extends undefined ? 1 : 2

function a<A extends string | undefined>(b: A): Ret<A> {
    if (b === undefined) {
        return 1 as Ret<A>
    } else {
        return 2 as Ret<A>
    }
}
```

This works fine, I can call the function with both values from type union and it will compute correct type value:

```
const resultUndefined: 1 = a(undefined)
const resultString: 2 = a("bcd")
```

Is it possible to do the same with optional parameter? When I change the function signature and leave the body unchanged:

```
function b<A extends string>(b?: A): Ret<A> {
    if (b === undefined) {
        return 1 as Ret<A>
    } else {
        return 2 as Ret<A>
    }
}
```

Then I can't capture the information that `A` will be undefined when the function is called without parameters.

```
const resultUndefined2: 1 = b()
```

Will result in this compiler error.

```
const resultUndefined2: 1
Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'.ts(2322)
```

Can I somehow capture the information that the argument is optional and pass it into the `Rec`?

Comment: Using `//@ts-ignore` before `return 1` is not recommended.  `//@ts-ignore` should be used [**very sparingly**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments).  Could you please remove those directives and use type assertions like  `return 1 as Ret<A>` instead?  Otherwise, it's a distraction from the question you're trying to ask.

Comment: Ignoring the body of the function, you could use a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to tell the compiler that if it can't infer `A` then it should fall back to `undefined`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEB6vN) shows.  There are some caveats around that (nothing stops someone from calling `b<string>()`) and probably better approaches to the exact example here (I'd just use overloads I think) but that's the basic answer.

Comment: Does that address your question fully? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz those are pretty good solutions! As you say, the solution with the type default is breakable and the solution with overloads doesn't have very good story when using [JSDoc typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html) as described [here](https://austingil.com/typescript-function-overloads-with-jsdoc/).

Comment: Okay, so what do you want to see here in terms of a posted answer? JSDoc seems to be out of scope for the question as asked, but so do overloads, so I don't need to talk about them.  You could also do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKOQMW), which is more roundabout but is not so easily breakable.  Let me know how to proceed (and mention @jcalz again, thanks)

Comment: As you say, JSDoc is a bit out of scope, so the answer with overloads is the best one I think. I don't think they are out of scope. @jcalz

Comment: All right, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance. It might not be until tomorrow (getting close to bedtime in my time zone)

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem with

```
let one: 1;
let two: 2;
type Ret<A> = A extends undefined ? 1 : 2
declare function b<A extends string>(b?: A): Ret<A>;
```

is that it is impossible for `A` to be `undefined` (you [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it to `string`, after all) so the output type will always be `2`:

```
two = b("a"); // okay
one = b(undefined); // error, 2 not assignable to 1
one = b(); // error, 2 not assignable to 1
```

So let's re-constrain `A` to `string | undefined` to see the next problem:

---

```
declare function b<A extends string | undefined>(b?: A): Ret<A>;
```

Now things are fine as long as you pass an argument to `b()`:

```
two = b("a"); // okay
one = b(undefined); // okay
```

But when you don't pass an argument, the compiler can't infer `A` at all. There's nothing to tell it what `A` is supposed to be, so it falls back to the constraint, `string | undefined`, and thus `Ret<A>` is the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `1 | 2`:

```
one = b(); // error, 1 | 2 not assignable to 1
```

Also note that because `b` accepts `undefined` as an argument no matter what `A` is, in the (unlikely in practice) event that someone explicitly specifies the type argument, you can get strange results:

```
two = b<string>(undefined); // okay?!
two = b<string>(); // okay?!
```

---

The easiest fix is to just give the type parameter a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `undefined`, so when inference fails, it falls back to the default:

```
declare function b<A extends string | undefined = undefined>(b?: A): Ret<A>;
two = b("a"); // okay
one = b(undefined); // okay
one = b(); // okay
```

Now when you call `b()`, you get a value of type `1`.  The weirdness with explicitly specifying `A` persists:

```
two = b<string>(undefined); // okay?!
two = b<string>(); // okay?!
```

but this is strictly no worse than your original version and works correctly for reasonable uses of `b()`, so this might be sufficient for your purposes.

---

If you want to keep the general pattern of having a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function returning a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) but eliminate the possibility of a explicitly specifying the wrong thing, you could use a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) instead so that the type argument encodes the "possibly-zero-params" possibility instead of an [optional parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) which adds `undefined` to the parameter type and not to the generic.

Like this:

```
declare function b<P extends [string?]>(...b: P): Ret<P[0]>;
two = b("a"); // okay
one = b(undefined); // okay
one = b(); // okay

two = b<[string]>(undefined); // error!
```

So here, the type argument `P` corresponds to the array of parameters, so it's sort of like "`[A]`".  That means `P[0]` corresponds to `A`.  Now when you call `b("a")`, `P` is inferred as `["a"]` so `P[0]` is `"a"`; when you call `b(undefined)`, `P` is `[undefined]` so `P[0]` is `undefined`, and importantly, when you call `b()`, `P` is properly inferred as `[]`, and `P[0]` is still `undefined`.  So it is not possible to do this anymore without the compiler complaining:

```
two = b<[string]>(undefined); // error!  
two = b<[string]>(); // error!
```

You *could* call `b<[string?]>()` or `b<[string?]>("a")`, in which case you'd get the union type `1 | 2` out, but this is just a caller intentionally widening things for some reason; it's not incorrect (the output really is `1 | 2`), just weird.

---

Anyway, for a call signature like this, it's probably more ergonomic just to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead of generic functions that return conditional types.  You just add one call signature for each way it should be called:

```
declare function b(b?: undefined): 1;
declare function b(b: string): 2;

two = b("a"); // okay
one = b(undefined); // okay
one = b(); // okay
```

And now it's impossible to call it with weird generic instantiations. You can either call it like `b()` or `b(undefined)`, or like `b("someString")`.  You can't even call it like `b(Math.random()<0.5?"a":undefined)` without the compiler stopping you.  If you want to support that, you could add a third call signature for it:

```
declare function b(b?: string): 1 | 2;
```

Overloads have their own caveats and issues, but I'd say they aren't really worse than generic conditional types, so the approach you should take depends on your use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gdiBcECMBuAUKSYDuVECZ0wBPABxAgCVwAeAQQD4IBeCOiEADzBBgBMAzhACu-EADMAlnD4QA-MggE0aGAEMAtiAGk1AYwoB5AE6SA5hADeaCBD4g9wNcYrjResJNgQARvQ7cvIIQAmCmMGYMABQ+coh0AJSI1GD0DOi2OFAsvlEARGp5CSgQAPSl0ADWasQ20HA5PlGi9lIyxWUVIMbGUMYANBD4EDBQkGoCAubqPqAQYNlIdbAUrE0d5Rw9fYPDo+OT02qzFAvIaAC+KupaOvoU1HqwocZq0lZ19o7Oru6e3n52FwePwhC9pBYAD4iMRtEB8aKxeJJKi0RgZea4Rr5QobCpQaq1WwrbEtCTSeF4qo1ZYNNZRKndXoDRTQvZjCATKZmGZzM5LOpZRo0cERaJkuF8KkEmpyACEgqxaxFYQh0WlhPlKiuqk02l0BggAHVJGAABYAEQkamEwEg1lsXycLggbhgHi8MF8-mBQTBqoiEGhEopslYIZkiLibBRKTSGKF9IKRRKmxlRPqq1yEcpqfxhNpWfWeeptUV2WVosizVhoY1soVmSV3qr6pL6a1l2ueruhuooQACs5NB9Pg5nb93f8vX4BwEQcEANpVuQAXWiADot4ufKvEAPY7QB4uAAzrhPNprJ+sZkn0nNS9sF4l03I3lRNive5cBszrmutHWJZMn0cq2OWwo-uEf5tp0WzMgqOrdrcBpGAAbt0wBQGosjWGO3wum6HoAjE0YPiiqD4ROrp-J6uQ+IgVYooQVE-DRU50U0SIhL+FFBkM6AQUmuJPjSL5FgB5LtKJt6vsWcHppcQA)

```
one = b<[string?]>(); // error, 1 | 2 not assignable to 1
```

when you call `b()` with no argument, the compiler